# Edit table cell style and spaces

Tags: tables, cell

I'm struggling with tables in latex. I would like to have the following "word" effect:

[image: word style]

but with the code:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\textbf{INGESTION (Hz)} & \textbf{3 STREAMS} & \textbf{6 STREAMS}  \\ \toprule
\rowcolor{black!10}[0pt][0pt]50    & 1  & 1   \\
25    & 2  & 2 \\
\rowcolor{black!10}[0pt][0pt]15    & 3  & 3
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

I obtain this:

[image: latex result]

which is very ugly to me.
Essentially I want to remove the space between the header and the first row, moreover I want remove the space between the cells of the rows (I used \arraystrech with terrible results).
I'd like to add the extra header also.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). You can take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149841/booktab-color-rows-with-multicolumn and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177202/booktabs-and-row-color?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The horizontal white strip is due to the padding added by the rules of booktabs. To remove it, you have to use `\specialrule` command, which gives you control on this padding for specific rules. The intercolumn white spaces are due to the optional [0pt]s in `\rowcolor`. Just suppress them. However a better solution, for alternating row colors is to use the `\rowcolors` command defined by `xcolor` with `[table]` option. Tthis option loads `colortbl`, so you don't have to do it.

Here's the result:
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}

```
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \rowcolors{3}{Gainsboro}{white}
  \begin{tabular}{c c c}
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{AVERAGE DATA LOSS (\%)}}\\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{INGESTION (Hz)} & \textbf{3 STREAMS} & \textbf{6 STREAMS} \\
    \specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
    50 & 1 & 1 \\
    25 & 2 & 2 \\
    15 & 3 & 3 \
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I find this the simple way.
do you have any suggestions to add an extra header like the "word" style?

Comment: @AndreaGiordano: Do you mean something like ‘Average Data Loss’ in your post?

Comment: yes, I would like to add it

Comment: @AndreaGiordano: The code has been updated, mylord!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`tabularx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). To center the column type `X` you use column type `Y` defined in [Centering in tabularx and X columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89932/124842).

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
  \rowcolors{3}{black!10}{white}  
  \begin{tabularx}{0.76\textwidth}{Ycc}
  \textbf{INGESTION (Hz)} & \textbf{3 STREAMS} & \textbf{6 STREAMS}  \\ \toprule
50    & 1  & 1   \\
25    & 2  & 2 \\
15    & 3  & 3
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a customized command to color the rows

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\colorlet{tablerowcolor}{black!10} % Table row separator colour = 10% gray
\newcommand{\rowcol}{\rowcolor{tablerowcolor}} %

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htpb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}\toprule
\textbf{INGESTION(Hz)} & \textbf{3 STREAMS}& \textbf{6 STREAMS} \\ \toprule
\rowcol         50      & 1                     & 1             \\
                25      & 2                     & 2             \\
\rowcol         15      & 3                     & 3             \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]